# aggregate nested array of objects using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following model and I want to query a specific user on _id field and populate the inbox.messages array with the necessary data that matches the corresponding _id field in the users model and more importantly i also want to group each message by the 'from' field and return that result

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    blockedUsers: {
        users: [
            {
                userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
            }
        ]
    },
    favorites: {
        users: [
            {
                userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
            }
        ]
    },
    profileViews: {
        views: [
            {
                userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
                date: {type: Date}
            }
        ]
    },
    inbox: {
        messages: [
            {
                messageId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
                from: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
                content: {type: String, required: true},
                date: {type: Date}
            }
        ]
    },
    images: {
        "imagePaths": [
            {   
                imageId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
                path: { type: String, required: true},
                date: {type: Date}
            }
        ],
    }
})
```

what I have so far

```
  let incomingId = '5e29fd75fdfd5320d0e42bc4';
  let myUser = await User.aggregate([
           { $match: {"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(incomingId) }},
           { $lookup: { }}
         ])
```

Not sure exactly what to put in the $lookup field or if this is even correct.

As a sample I would like the documents to look like:

```
[
  {
    "from": "5e240f7480a24e07d832c7bd",
    "username":"hable0",
    "images": {
      imagePaths: [
         'images/2020-09-24-Z_34234342_12.jpg'
      ],
     },
    "inbox": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "messageId": "5e2a110a21c64d63f451e39e",
          "content": "Message content",
          "date": "2020-01-23T21:32:58.126Z"
        },
        {
          "messageId": "5e2a111321c64d63f451e3a0",
          "content": "Message content",
          "date": "2020-01-23T21:33:07.378Z"
        },
        {
          "messageId": "5e2a112321c64d63f451e3a2",
          "content": "Message content",
          "date": "2020-01-23T21:33:23.036Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include some sample documents to test along with your expected JSON output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following pipeline with `aggregate()`.

- Find the document that matches the id
- Unwind `inbox.messages`
- Group by `from` field
- Perform a `$lookup` to get another document
- Perform a `$unwind` to destruct the array
- Specify fields to be included in the output

```
let myUser = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(incomingId) }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$inbox.messages"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { from: "$inbox.messages.from" },
      messages: {
        $push: {
          messageId: "$inbox.messages.messageId"
          // Add more info of the message here as needed
        }
      }
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "User",
      localField: "_id.from",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "extraUserInfo"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$extraUserInfo"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      from: "$_id.from",
      inbox: { messages: "$messages" },
      username: "$extraUserInfo.username",
      images: "$extraUserInfo.images"
    }
  }
]);
```

**Sample output:**

```
{
  "from": "user1",
  "inbox": {
    "messages": [{
      "messageId": "message1-from-user1"
    }]
  },
  "username": "user1-username",
  "images": {
    "imagePaths": ["image-path-user1"]
  }
} {
  "from": "user2",
  "inbox": {
    "messages": [{
      "messageId": "message1-from-user2"
    }, {
      "messageId": "message2-from-user2"
    }, {
      "messageId": "message3-from-user2"
    }]
  },
  "username": "user2-username",
  "images": {
    "imagePaths": ["image-path-user2"]
  }
} {
  "from": "user3",
  "inbox": {
    "messages": [{
      "messageId": "message1-from-user3"
    }, {
      "messageId": "message2-from-user3"
    }]
  },
  "username": "user3-username",
  "images": {
    "imagePaths": ["image-path-user3"]
  }
}
```

Hope this answers part of your question. Though I'm not very clear how you would like to populate the `messages` array with the user info who sent the messages. But you can perform a `$lookup()` with a pipeline after `$group()` operation to attach additional info from the sender to the result.

Read more about [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Comment: Yes this is starting to look like what I want but I there is also a username field on the User model and imagePaths field, I would like to grab these as  well and put the with information. Could you give an example of  performing a $lookup? I still don't quite understand it.

Comment: @WoodsD I updated my answer to include a `$lookup`. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: now I get an empty array. Where before I was getting the results just as you displayed them

Comment: Oh maybe, there was a typo. I was performing a lookup on `Users` instead of `User`. Please help me check all the variable names to make sure they're correct since I don't have a full setup like yours. Updated the answer btw.

Comment: I checked and changed Users from User. That didn't help either could it be because this is a self-reference. Should I think about adjusting the document structure and putting this data into a separate collection?

Comment: That's strange. Did you check that the `from` field in your collection is of type `ObjectId` as well? Here is the script that I tried in MongoDB and I got the expected output: https://jsfiddle.net/o4afh8s6/10/

Comment: Well in the results returned the from field is a string. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the fact im now getting empty results. Its only when I add the $lookup code you provided is when there is empty results. I have made a fiddle  See here https://jsfiddle.net/78rac1qw/2/